# Rearrange signal spectrum after a shuffle

Tags: signals, signal-processing, spectrum

So i want to create a function/algorithm that takes a shuffled sprectrum and returns the spectrum original form.

The initial spectrum of a wav file is this:
[original spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0XEj.png)

After this i cut the spectrum into 4 parts and shuffle them, then creating a new wave form with those values and then the spectrum,it looks like this:
[sprectum after shuffle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1e2P.png)

So based off the shuffle spectrum i need to get the original spectrum. Most likely i have to split the shuffle spectrum into ... lets say 4 parts and using brute force to check every combination.

But this is my question , when i compare 2 parts of the spectrum , how do i know which one should be first and which to be the second?

This is my Wave and Spectrum class :

```
class Wave:

def __init__(self,data,ts=None,framerate=None):

    # data:wave data values
    # ts:array of time where the signal was evaluated/sampled


    self.data=data
    self.framerate=framerate

    if ts is None:
        self.ts =np.arange(len(data))/self.framerate
    else:
        self.ts=ts

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data)


@property
def duration(self):

    return len(self.data) / self.framerate

def make_spectrum(self):

    n=len(self.data)
    d=1/self.framerate

    ampArray = np.fft.rfft(self.data)
    freqArray = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, d) 

    return Spectrum(ampArray,freqArray,self.framerate)

def plot(self):

    plt.plot(self.ts,self.data)  

class Spectrum:

def __init__(self,ampArray,freqArray,framerate):

    self.ampArray=ampArray
    self.freqArray=freqArray
    self.framerate=framerate


def plot(self):

    plt.plot(self.freqArray,np.absolute(self.ampArray))

def make_wave(self,dataLength):

    data=np.fft.irfft(self.ampArray,dataLength);
    return Wave(data,framerate=self.framerate)

def shuffle(self):

    listZip=list(zip(self.ampArray,self.freqArray))   # list of tuples ( amplitude value,frequency value)
    listToShuffle=list(chunks(listZip,4))        # split the list in 4 list
    random.shuffle(listToShuffle)                # randomize the 4 lists
    flat_list = [item for sublist in listToShuffle for item in sublist]  
    random_ampArray,random_freqArray= zip(*flat_list)
    return Spectrum(random_ampArray,random_freqArray,self.framerate)
```

Comment: If you shuffle the spectrum while always using the same random sequence, you would know how to rearrange your spectrum after the shuffling operation. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not, it has to be a different sequence every time, but even if i was using the same sequence , i'm suppose to rearrange the spectrum without knowing anything about the initial spectrum , only that is shuffled.

Comment: Well, I am afraid this is not possible. You can not revert some randomizing process without any additional information about this process. Maybe somehow encoding the randomization sequence within your spectrum would be an option but I am not sure how to achieve this.